# Adding information to transport package manifest (instructions.xml) when unpublishing any item?

Tags: tridion

I have a use case where I need to add information about the user that created the current publish transaction (more than just their user name, I also need group memberships and some other details) and pass it on to a deployer extension.

When publishing this is relatively easy to do with the following code

```
engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddInstruction(
                                      InstructionScope.Global, instruction);
```

As you may notice this method "AddInstruction" is only available for a "RenderedItem", but **Unpublish** instructions do not render items, and therefore I cannot use the same technique.

Short of hacking the package manifest in the file system when generating it (for instance in a custom resolver) how would you tackle this requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have more info on what you need to do with this information in the Deployer. Would it be an option to capture the un-publish action after it happens with an event handler, and then create a second publish action which sends the message to the Deployer with the additional information? (I know that means 2 round trips, but I can't think of another approach at this point). Un-publish actions have been a bit tricky ever since R4, back in R3 we actually had code which was executed by templates in the unpublish phase (although it was all Perl back then).

Comment: Thanks Chris, that might actually be the easiest way forward. I will file an Enhancement Request anyway.
I'll discuss having a "special" component or page published only for the purpose of passing this type of information, and the deployer extension will have to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder whether this is a missing extensibility point. After all, I can see why you would want to transmit extra data with an unpublish. So firstly, I'd suggest an enhancement request to have some functionality added to support this use case.

Getting to the point of your question... how to implement something without hacking the package. Perhaps you could make the information available through another mechanism. For example, you could write a web service that runs on the content manager and which serves the data when queried for a given publish transaction ID.

Comment: I think that indeed it is a missing extensibility point. Enhancement Request filed.